# JOIN THREE TABLES IN CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I have three tables

1.article (id,article_title)

2.article_status(id,article_id,stage_id)

3.article_stages(id,stage_name)

Each article have multiple insertion in table 2. I want to fetch the last value which indicate the current stage using join query

**article**

id  article_title

```
1   article1
2   article2
```

**article_status**

```
id   article_id   stage_id
1     1             1
2     1             2
3     1             3
4     2             1
```

**article_stages**

```
id  stage_name  
1    Stage1            
2    Stage2  
3    Stage3
```

I need the result like

```
id  article_title  stage_name
1   article1       Stage3
2   article2       Stage1
```

Here is my query

```
"SELECT `article`.`article_title` as id,`article`.`article_title`,`article_stages`.`stage_name`, MAX(`article_status`.`stage_id`) AS stage_id FROM (`article`)
JOIN `article_status` ON `article_status`.`article_id`=`article`.`id`
JOIN `article_stages` ON `article_stages`.`id` = (SELECT MAX(`stage_id`) FROM `article_status` )
GROUP BY `article_status`.`article_id`"
```

I tried this

```
public function getAllArticleforIssue($condition = array())
{
            $table1 = 'article';
            $table2 = 'article_status';
            $table3 ='article_stages';      
            $this->db->select($table1.'.id as id,'.$table1.'.article_title,'.$table3.'.stage_name');
            $this->db->select_max($table2.'.stage_id');
            $this->db->from('rsgp_article');
            $this->db->join($table2,$table2.'.article_id='.$table1.'.id');
            $this->db->join($table3 , $table3.'.id = '.$table2.'.stage_id'); 
            if (count($condition) > 0)
            $this->db->where($condition);
            $this->db->group_by($table2.".article_id"); 
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result_array();
   }
```

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i tried the sql query

Comment: `artcle_title (used in table structure)  !== article_title(used in query)` and what is `rsgp_article_status`?

Comment: @AlivetoDie sorry its my mistake.. table name is article_status

Comment: I would suggest you to first group your article status table and then join to article and article_stages. Grouping table first reduces joining time.

Comment: Hi! You have now given us lots of details of what you're trying to do, and what you've tried, but I still don't see a description of what problem you are encountering - does your current code give an error? Or does it give a different result than you wanted? Be as specific as you can.

Answer (score 1):

Query Explanation:

1. Find article_id and current_stage_id ( see subquery groupedTable)
2. join with article and article_stages table in order to get
   description.

SQL:

```
select article_id, article_title, stage_name  
from ( select article_id , max(stage_id) as current_Stage_ID
       from article_status
       group by article_id ) groupedTable 
join article on article.id = groupedTable.article_id
join article_stages on article_stages.id = groupedTable.current_Stage_ID
```

PHP:

```
function function_name() { 
       $sql = "select article_id, article_title, stage_name  
       from ( select article_id , max(stage_id) as current_Stage_ID
       from article_status
       group by article_id ) groupedTable join article on article.id = groupedTable.article_id
       join article_stages on article_stages.id = groupedTable.current_Stage_ID";
       $query = $this -> db -> query($sql);
       $result = $query -> result_array();
       return $result;
    }
```

Comment: @Ann Have you tried above query. is it helpful or not ?

Comment: i need to include where condition also

Comment: Could you please explain about your condition as well ?

Comment: there are more colums in article table, like issue_no , journal_code,accode etc i need to fetch the data with condition like $condition = array("issue_no " => NULL,"journal_code"=>$jnl);  I need to send condition as argument from controller

Comment: You just have to make condition and put it in proper place. You can also accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
SELECT    a.article_title,s.stage_name
FROM      article a
JOIN      (
              SELECT    MAX(stage_id) max_id, article_id 
              FROM      article_status 
              GROUP BY  article_id
          ) b ON (b.article_id = a.article_id)
JOIN      article_stages s ON (s.id = b.max_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
SELECT    a.id,a.artcle_title,s.stage_name
FROM      article a
JOIN      (
              SELECT    MAX(stage_id) max_id, article_id 
              FROM      article_status 
              GROUP BY  article_id
          ) b ON (b.article_id = a.id)
JOIN      article_stages s ON (s.id = b.max_id)
```

With ID Column...

modified answer of - @Roshan Dandgavhal

Comment: Explaining what the query does would be nice.

Comment: Copy paste my answer

Comment: @RoshanDandgavhal - there is some error in your ans, and some more result column added.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
$this->db->select('a.id, a.article_title, c.stage_name');
$this->db->from('article a');
$this->db->join('article_status b','b.article_id=a.id','left');
$this->db->join('article_stage c','c.id=b.article_status', 'left');
$this->db->group_by('a.article_name');
$this->db->get()->result_array();
```